# Top show high CPU on process but idle on load average

Tags: asterisk, load-average

I am running FreePBX on DigitalOcean VM. I am facing some call dropping issue in Asterisk. When looking at "htop", "top" and FreePBX GUI, I see different results of CPU utilization and can't understand if my VM is OK or needs attention w.r.t CPU. Load average shows nearly idle system while CPU utilization of Asterisk process is pretty high.

htop result:
[image]

top result:
[image]

FreePBX GUI result:

[image]

Could someone please advise me on this? 74% CPU on a process yet idle system on load average. Can this be an issue causing call dropping on Asterisk?

Comment: I don't seem to find answer to my question in past questions. My question is specifically about a situation where a process is showing high % of CPU and load average is nearly idle on a dual core VM. Is my CPU really busy? Please refer me to an old question for reading around it.

Comment: Rephrased question and provided specific issue.